# Managing production and beta Android apps with Subversion VCS

Tags: android, android-studio, svn, apk

Given an application being developed on Android Studio where the VCS is configured to use Subversion, and where one wished to maintain a production and a beta release, what source control technique should be employed to manage this arrangement?

[image: subversion configuration in Android Studio]

Up until now, I have been working from only the head branch and have no other branches.  What is in the head now (369) contains a bunch of features that are in beta, but are not ready for production.  But the production version (365) needs a fix.

I'm looking for Subersion specific advice for how to proceed.  I'm kind of scared to do anything, because a fumble here could be a real PITA.  I want to be able to work on a production release and a beta release with tight control on what is in each, but am not sure the exact buttons to push in the UI.

Right-clicking on "app", and selecting `Subversion > Branch or Tag`, I get to the `Create Branch or Tag` dialog.  In the `Copy From` section, I suppose I would select `Repository Location` and specify 365 (the version that's currently in production that needs the fix applied).  The latest version (with the beta features) is 369.

[image: create branch or tag dialog]

But what is the `Base URL` supposed to be?  What's going on here, physically?  Is it really going to make a second copy of the project or just make some construct that I can switch to when I want to operate on that version?  And then, presuming creating a branch or tag is what I really need, how do I switch between the two versions and build APK's from those different versions concurrently, one to production and one to beta?

I hope there's someone out there that manages all of this without breaking out into the command line, since I've not gone there and don't want to go there.

Comment: my recommendation is you should learn and understand the command line, because all GUI not contains all features of CVS.

Comment: The problem I'm having goes beyond whether or not a command line is used.  The problem is I don't know what the SVN terminology is, what steps should be taken, how the situation is typically managed, etc.  I'm sure that the GUI has enough features for what I want to do.